# aes-x86_64.ko No such file or directory for Module Installation failure after 4.12.9 Kernel compilation

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

### THE SCENARIO

I'm writing a demo module to be inserted in Kernel and then write on system, for which I've already made entries in Header file and Table file.

### PROCEDURE FOLLOWED SO FAR

I compiled the kernel using

```
/linux-4.12.9$ sudo make -j4
```

In which I got some warnings and NO ERROR. Unable to grab those warnings anyway, since terminal has overflown.

After no errors, I fired

```
/linux-4.12.9$ sudo make modules_install install
```

### THE PROBLEM

which returns

```
INSTALL arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko cp: cannot stat 'arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko': No such file or directory At main.c:291:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178 
sign-file: /lib/modules/4.12.9/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko: No such file or directory 
scripts/Makefile.modinst:35: recipe for target 'arch/x86/crypto/aes- x86_64.ko' failed 
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko] Error 1 
        Makefile:1237: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed 
        make[1]: *** [_modinst_] Error 2 
        Makefile:527: recipe for target '__build_one_by_one' failed make: *** [__build_one_by_one] Error 2
```

I've posted the working directory as well in the command above, in case I'm doing it in wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with supported libraries and packages I was using.
To compile the latest kernel at this time of writing, you must have these 4 Packages / Libraries installed:

1. libssl-dev
2. libncurses5-dev
3. qt4-default
4. qt4-dev-tools

Although I'm bit skeptical about qt4's *dev-tools* and *default*, since I've downloaded together.

Also Note,
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and based on your Distro commands and package requirement are subject to change

### The Compilation

So the above mentioned command (In question) for compilation is correct, just notice that it takes a pretty much time to complete. To verify if everything is going smooth, you reach at a point where you can find this -

```
Setup is 17564 bytes (padded to 17920 bytes).
System is 7215 kB
CRC 3b136d62
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
```

and it halts there for few mins and starts again with creation of object files. Yes, I didn't receive when I was first doing it with qt5 packages.

### The Installation

Again the above mentioned command (In question) is cent percent correct and on firing same you'll see multiple Kernel objects installing in your system, something like this:

```
...
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/emi62/spdif.fw
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/emi62/midi.fw
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/kaweth/new_code.bin
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/kaweth/trigger_code.bin
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/kaweth/new_code_fix.bin
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/kaweth/trigger_code_fix.bin
  INSTALL /lib/firmware/ti_3410.fw
...
```

and it must end with

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.12.9
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.12.9
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-93-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-83-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

> **NOOB ALERT**
>
> Also please note, based on number of Operating Systems (and Kernel) installed on
>   your system the number of **Found** statements may change! I have 2 OS
>   and hence I've got one extra **Found** statement for Windows